# Why is the JVM hanging up?

Tags: java, jvm, infinite-loop

I think this can be solved with setting traps/breakpoints - but I'm not quite sure on how to do that. This method is supposed to sort an array of objects (each object contains an int, which is a year), but I get nothing on the terminal, and a busy VM signal... What's going on?

```
public static movie2[] sortYear(movie2[] sort, int parameter)
{
    int[] dest = new int[sort.length];
    if(parameter == 1)
    {

    for(int i = 0; i < sort.length-1; i++)
    {
        int next = sort[i].getYear();
        int insertIndex = 0;
        int k = i; //Why do I need this?
        while( k > 0 && insertIndex == 0)
        {
            if(next > dest[k-1])
            {
                insertIndex = k;
            }
            else
            {
                dest[insertIndex] = next;
            }


       }
       sort[i].setYear(dest[i]);

    }
```

Comment: Debug your code step by step and you should quickly understand the issue.

Comment: How - I was not taught about setting traps and breakpoints, so could you suggest some lines to set - or do I even need those?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the first `if` and then step through line by line.

Comment: Have you tried `System.out.println`? It's not the same as stepping through with a debugger but it's much better than just staring at a blank console...

Comment: You never decrement `k` in your `while` loop. If `k` is greater than 0 and `insertIndex` is not 0 you get an infinite loop.

Comment: If you want help from others, you might need to create a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (I created one, but could not reproduce the error - although I'm not sure what you are doing there at all, and it does not seem to make much sense for me). Otherwise, you might want to insert `System.out.println("At end of loop, k is "+k+" and insertIndex is "+insertIndex);` as the last line of your `while` loop.